# rlang !! error when !! sym()

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyeval

Similar to this: [pass function arguments to both dplyr and ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45439813/pass-function-arguments-to-both-dplyr-and-ggplot?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa#)

I have in the past used !!sym() without any rememberable headache.

However, now I get an error when I try this:

```
library(rlang)
library(tidyverse)


diamond_plot <- function (data, group, metric) {
    quo_group  <- sym(group)
    quo_metric <- sym(metric)

    data %>%
        group_by(!! quo_group) %>%
        summarise(price = mean(!! quo_metric)) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = !! quo_group, y = !! quo_metric)) +
        geom_col()
}

diamond_plot(diamonds, "clarity", "price")
```

The error is

```
Error in !quo_group : invalid argument type
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: The code works for me. Have you tried updating `rlang` and all `tidyverse` packages?

Comment: What version of `ggplot` are you using? It has only been very recently updated to support `!!` inside `aes()` calls. You currently need the development version.

Comment: Thanks - I have updated everything - and now it works. ggplot2_2.2.1.9000 is ggplot2 version