# Unable to reuse variable names in ggplot due to lazy evaluation

Tags: r, ggplot2, lazy-evaluation

I am producing a ggplot with many similar elements. To assist I have designed a function that produces a single element, which I plan to reuse. For example

```
reusable.element = function(gg, params){
    x = some.calculation(params)
    y = some.calculation(params)
    gg + geom_line(aes(x,y))
}
gg = ggplot()
gg = reusable.element(gg, params1)
gg = reusable.element(gg, params2)
print(gg)
```

However, R then complains that it can not find `x`.

As best as I can determine this appears to be due to lazy evaluation. R is trying to evaluate `x` only when printing the plot. For example:

```
x1 = c(1,1)
y1 = c(1,2)
p = ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x1,y1))
x1 = c(1)
y1 = c(3)
p = p + geom_point(aes(x1,y1))
p
```

Produces a plot of only one point, because `x1 = c(1)` overrides `x1 = c(1,1)`.

I know I can get around this by assigning different variables names. For example:

```
x1 = c(1,1)
y1 = c(1,2)
p = ggplot() + geom_point(aes(eval(x1),eval(y1)))
x2 = c(1)
y2 = c(3)
p = p + geom_point(aes(x2,y2))
p
```

(Produces the intended plot of 3 dots). But this will significantly reduce the effectiveness of any function that produces a single plot element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer only after writing out my entire question: [Force evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021021/force-ggplot-to-evaluate-counter-variable)

In short, using `aes_` instead of `aes` forces evaluation of the aesthetic at the time it is written (preventing lazy evaluation at the time the figure is drawn, and enabling figure elements to be built within a function).

Following the comment from @camille here is an approach without using `aes_`. Note that you may have to update to the most recent version of `tidyverse` and `rlang` packages to get this working.

```
x1 = c(1,1)
y1 = c(1,2)
p = ggplot() + geom_point(aes(!!enquo(x1),!!enquo(y1)))
x1 = c(1)
y1 = c(1)
p
```

I think of this as `enquo` is evaluate'n'quote and `!!` as unquote. So `!!enquo` forces evaluation of the variable at the time it is called.

Comment: FYI `aes_` and `aes_string` are being deprecated in favor of tidyeval in `ggplot`. There was a question [earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51658629/5325862) dealing with this